# File pointer is 0x0 but all NULL checks fail

Tags: c, bash, unix, gdb

Apologies if this is a dumb question as I am new to C.

I'm trying to process a list of files in C. If fopen() returns NULL when opening a file, I skip over it; otherwise it is safe to keep going.

The problem is that all my NULL checks fail. None of the following if statements execute (and on a separate note, `fopen()` should not fail either as I am always providing a valid file path...).

EDIT: Someone requested I post all relevant code: Here it is, starting from main():

```
int num_words_to_show;
int max_occurrances;

FILE* fp = NULL;
char*** freq_arr = NULL;
HashTable* table = make_hash_table();

num_words_to_show = 10;

/* Populate hash table from input. Exit if could not populate. */
if (!populate_table(table, fp, argc, argv, &num_words_to_show)) {
    fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", USAGE_ERR);
    return 1;
}
```

Now the function in question:

```
int populate_table(HashTable* table, 
                   FILE* fp, 
                   int argc, 
                   char* argv[], 
                   int* num_words_to_show) {
    int filename_index;

/* Description for input_is_valid():
If input is invalid, prints error messages and returns -1.
Else if no input file specified, return -2.
Otherwise, returns starting index of filenames and
sets variable determining how many values to show.
*/
    filename_index = input_is_valid(argc, argv, num_words_to_show);

    if (filename_index == -1) {
        return 0;
    }
    else if (filename_index == -2) {
        printf("%s\n", "Index is -2");
        parse_words(table, NULL);
    }
    else {
        /* Loop through all opened files. */
        for (; filename_index < argc; ++filename_index) {
            fp = fopen(argv[filename_index], "r");

            if (!fp) { /* DOES NOT EXECUTE */
                perror(argv[filename_index]);
                continue;
            }

            if (fp == NULL) { /* DOES NOT EXECUTE */
                printf("%s\n", "File is null");
                continue;
            }

            if (fp == 0x0) { /* DOES NOT EXECUTE */
                printf("Comparison to literal 0 failed.");
                continue;
            }

            parse_words(table, fp); /* <-- Causes segfault as not expecting NULL for fp */
            fclose(fp);
        }
    }

    return 1;
```

The last conditional has a value I took straight from GDB and still fails. Here is GDB output:

```
Breakpoint 1, populate_table (table=0x603010, fp=0x0, argc=2, argv=0x7fffffffe338, num_words_to_show=0x7fffffffe234) at fw.c:80
80              if (!fp) {
(gdb) s
Breakpoint 2, populate_table (table=0x603010, fp=0x0, argc=2, argv=0x7fffffffe338, num_words_to_show=0x7fffffffe234) at fw.c:85
85              if (fp == NULL) {
(gdb) s
Breakpoint 3, populate_table (table=0x603010, fp=0x0, argc=2, argv=0x7fffffffe338, num_words_to_show=0x7fffffffe234) at fw.c:90
90              if (fp == 0x0) {
(gdb) s
94              parse_words(table, fp);
(gdb) p fp
$1 = (FILE *) 0x0
```

Any tips would be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Clarify in question, what you mean by `If a file is NULL`

Comment: @sjsam Sorry, I meant file pointer (`fp`) is NULL. As in, `fopen()` returned NULL on failure.

Comment: Have you tried compiling with all warning turned on (`-Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic`)? / Did you compile with `-g` when run the program with GDB?

Comment: @user202729 yes I did, otherwise GDB would not get the information it needed to set breakpoints and the output above would not have happened.

Comment: What about the former question? (warning)

Comment: Can you make a **minimal** compilable example? Eyeballing the code doesn't seem to help solving it in this case, and a single UB somewhere may kill the whole program.

Comment: There is really no point passing `fp` into your function, since the value passed in is never used. While it is completely legal to use a parameter as a temporary, it could well confuse `gdb` (as well as people trying to read your code) especially if you compile with optimisation. It is quite possible that `gdb` is not showing you the correct value for `fp`. Use `-O0` to give yourself  a fighting chance.

Comment: Sry, not meant offending, but are you sure you are compiling the code you are editing, and linking the result you actually compiled?

Comment: Could you also add `printf` output of `fp` immediately after `fp = fopen(argv[filename_index], "r");` and post whole program output?

Comment: "*Someone requested I post all relevant code*" -- Please do so. There is no `main` function in the code you're shown us. You've shown us two separate chunks of code, not a complete program. I should be able to copy-and-paste your code from the question, compile it on my own machine, and reproduce the problem. If possible create a narrowed version of your own program, removing anything not directly relevant to the problem. You should be able to get it down to, say, 20-30 lines (and in the process you might solve the problem yourself). Read this: [mcve]

Comment: @KeithThompson that's what I did, and as you predicted, I came to (somewhat) of a solution. Thank you for the advice! I apologize for any StackOverflow mishaps as I am still a student. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Strangely, GDB was showing NULL, but when I printed the value, it was not null. The theory is that a buffer overflow somewhere "confused" GDB.

Unfortunately I cannot post the entire source code on a public forum, but this is the best answer I have. Regardless, the problem is fixed, though I am not entirely sure why GDB showed the wrong value.

Answer (score 0):

When fp is null, your first comparison `if (!fp)` is true, and executes a`continue`. `continue` means ‘start the next loop cycle’, so the CPU goes right back to the `for`, and starts the next iteration. The other `if`s are never reached.

Comment: My problem is that the if statement is never executed. The debugger shows that none of the if statements are entered.

Comment: Post the remaining code. For all we know, `filename_index` is uninitialized and starts its life with the value 638463858. That would result in UD when `argv[]` is accessed, and anything after that is random behavior.

Comment: Updated the post. Hope this helps and thanks for looking at this!

Comment: @Aganju: I think you mean UB (undefined behavior).

Comment: @Aganju ...? It is assign to right below the declaration.

Comment: Ok, check in the debugger what is in `filename_index`. Otherwise I see nothing else wrong. Could it be that `input_is_valid` destroys the stack or argv?